# Decreasing of char matrix

Tags: c++, string, matrix, c-strings, postfix-notation

I have a `char` matrix of width lets say 7, that include figures and signs. After doing mathematical operations I need to decrease the matrix size and rewrite it, I do all of that on the existing matrix, by function:

```
template<typename T>
T** Squeeze(T**Digits, int&size, int k, int i)
```

The only issue is that when i am trying to fix frame, when is the end of the matrix by putting - `\0` to the last one, it doesn't do it, instead it rewrites the first one element. I cant understand what's wrong with it.

```
template<typename T>
T** Squeeze(T**Digits, int&size, int k, int i)
{
    int c=0, j=0;
    for(int f=0, c=0; f<size; f++)
    {
        if(f==i-2)
        {
            sprintf(Digits[c],"%d",k);
            c++;
        }
        else if(f<i-2||f>=i+1)
        {
            strcpy(Digits[c], Digits[f]);
            c++;
        }
    }
    c++;
    Digits[c][j]='\0';
    size-=2;
    return Digits;
}
```

For example when I'm passing in:

- "10 3 2 - 4 * +" for `Digits`
- 15 for `size`
- 1 for `k`
- 6 for `i`

I expect `Digits` to be modified to contain: "10 1 - 4 * +" and `size` to be modified to contain 13.

Comment: Besides the initialization, where do you assign to `j` or modify it?

Comment: Thanks for respond, I dont use it nowhere, just at the end, to asign \0;

Comment: And at that point, what is the value of `j`? It's still zero, meaning you will replace the first character of `Digits[c]` with the terminator.

Comment: Yes the main targer is like this, cause signes takes only 1 elements in each array, so I need for it just the first one .

Comment: I'm no longer sure I understand what you mean with your question, can you please show how you use the function (like creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), and including the input you pass to the function as well as the actual and expected output?

Comment: Also, why is the function templated? It can only handle narrow-character (`char`) strings anyway? Anything else will cause the function to no longer compile or not work properly.

Comment: I need to solve the string mathematical expression with the method that calls 'Polish Notation', so I have a char string 10+(3-2)*4, after sorting I receive matrix of char strings: 10 3 2 - 4 * +

Comment: When I do mathematical operations first 3-2 is 1, so instead of 3 strings I will get 1  that is equeal to 1, it should looks like that: 10 1 4 * +

Comment: nest time ones again untill I will get the final result, so I need everytime to decrease the existing matrix

Comment: Lastly, this seems like a perfect opportunity to learn how to use a debugger, especially how to step through code line by line. That should help you figure things out.

Comment: I use template just to get acustomed to it, I undertsand that it has no influence in general in this case

Comment: Yes I am doing it half of the day, and finally decided to ask people, but as I see this question is not accepted very well,

Comment: 1) strcpy will copy more than one char 2) c and f have the same values up until  (i-2). You could just skip until that part.

Comment: @Melany adding your expected input and output as part of the question would probably help the question's acceptance.

Comment: Selçuk Cihan , thanks for comment, yes the main idea is to use c and f, to update the newer Matrix,.Concerning strcpy , yes it copies more than 1 symbol in case of digits, cause there could be 10, 500 and so on...

Comment: Jonathan Mee, yes thanks for advice, maybe its my main problem, and thats why after asking a question I am started to be blocked for 2 days....:( So I have a days off with stackoverflow:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This architecture is fundamentally broken:

1. It is taking in a C-String pointer and trying to treat it like a 2 dimensional array. How would a C-String pointer know anything about columns?
2. It is trying to replace the two numbers in the string but it isn't removing the operator.
3. There is no way to specify the number of characters to remove, the algorithm always replaces from [`i - 2`, `i`], this won't work for: `"10 3 +"`
4. `Digits` may not have sufficient room if power operators are allowed.
5. The size is passed but the C-String is null-terminated this is redundant information

So the inputs need work. But lets say I'm passed:

- `char* Digits` a pointer to a c-string guaranteed to be long enough to contain the output (this asserts a fix for **4**)
- `size_t& size` the current length of the `Digits` (this will fix **1**)
- `int k` the number to write starting at `Digits[i - replacementSize]`
- `size_t i` the end position for replacement which is guaranteed to be larger than `replacementSize`
- `int replacementSize` the number of characters to be replaced in `Digits` (this will fix **2** and **3**)

In this case [`copy_backward`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy_backward) and [`to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) can be used to solve the problem:

```
const auto replacementString = to_string(k);
const auto offset = static_cast<int>(replacementString.size()) - replacementSize;

copy_backward(Digits + i + 1, Digits + size, Digits + size + offset);
copy(replacementString.begin(), replacementString.end(), Digits + i - replacementSize);
size += offset;
```

[[Live Example](http://ideone.com/cy6hsZ)]

If null-termination is insisted on in-spite of **5** above just make sure that `size` includes the `'\0'` character in `Digits` and this algorithm will copy it.

Comment: Jonathan Mee, Thanks a lot:)  I didnt know nothing concerning  copy_backward and to_string, I will read concerning it,,  After hours of debugging i invent simplier way, but yours variant I will judge. Thanks a lot for help!!!!

Comment: @Melany Yup, if that solves your problem I'd encourage you to accept it. If you went a better route it would be helpful to people if you could post your own answer and accept that.

Comment: I am blocked for 2 days now, the only thing I can do its to wright a comment:(  I did it in this way:
template<typename T>
T** Squeeze(T**Digits, int &size, int k, int i)
{
 int c=0;
 int j=0;
 for(int f=0, c=0; f<size; f++)
 {
  if(f==i-2)
  {
   sprintf(Digits[c],"%d",k);
   c++;
  }
  else if(f<i-2||f>=i+1)
  {
   strcpy(Digits[c], Digits[f]);
   c++;
  }
 }
 /*c++;
 Digits[c][j]='\0';*/
 size-=2;
 return Digits;
}

Comment: @Melany Looks like you just commented out the `Digits[++c][j] = '\0';` That was my point **1** of the architectural problems. (Unfortunately there are 4 more that you still need to address.)

Comment: Jonathan Mee, yes you are right, I need to solve it completely...

Comment: @Melany Are you able to nominate this question for reopening? I can't remember if you need some amount of reputation to do that. If you can nominate for reopening it would be enough to push the question back to active and you could post answers again.

Comment: Jonathan Mee am still blocked, I dont have enough reputation. I suppose I will be again unblocked tommorow, I will try to reopen or ask the new one.